# I sometimes get weird behaviour from the UICollectionView cells

Tags: ios, swift

This problem is very hard for me to debug but easy for me to reproduce. I don't understand it.

Here is the problem:

[image]

Sometimes the text in some of the chat messages are of opposite color. I have to do pagination 3 times to reproduce this bug. 80 messages in total needs to be loaded for this bug to appear. I have to scroll almost all the way to the top, and then slowly scroll downwards until "Works" becomes black. Sometimes it is not black, sometimes it is white. Also the bubble colors and position are always correct, only the text color is off sometimes.

I am trying to make a chat application and set up the cells in a function like this:

```
    internal func setupCell(cell: MessagesCell, message: Message, indexPath: IndexPath, lastReadMessageIndex: Int, timeLabelHeight: CGFloat) {
        // Setting bubbleWidth for all cells.
        cell.bubbleViewWidthAnchor?.constant = estimateFrame(message: message).width + 20 + 6
        let cellSpacing = calculateCellSpacing(messages: messages, indexPath: indexPath)
        if messageDisplaysTime(messages: messages, indexPath: indexPath) {
            cell.bubbleViewTopAnchor?.constant = timeLabelHeight
            cell.timeLabel.text = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: Double(message.createdTime)).messageTime()
            cell.timeLabel.isHidden = false
        } else {
            cell.bubbleViewTopAnchor?.constant = 0
            cell.timeLabel.isHidden = true
        }
        cell.bubbleViewBottomAnchor?.constant = -cellSpacing
        cell.profileImageViewBottomAnchor?.constant = -cellSpacing
        // Messages from me.
        if message.isFromMe() {
            cell.bubbleView.backgroundColor = MessagesCell.bubbleBlueColor
//            // The reason we have to put it here as well is because cells do get reused, so we have to be careful about resetting the color.
            cell.messageTextView.textColor = .white
            cell.bubbleViewLeftAnchor?.isActive = false
            cell.bubbleViewRightAnchor?.isActive = true
            cell.profileImageView.isHidden = true
            if indexPath.item == lastReadMessageIndex {
                // Need to double check that it is actually viewed because lastReadMessageIndex can be 0 and still not read because of default value.
                if message.isViewed {
                    cell.isViewedImageViewBottomAnchor?.constant = -cellSpacing
                    guard let partnerImageName = user?.imageName else { return }
                    cell.isViewedImageView.loadImage(urlString: User.imageURL(imageName: partnerImageName))
                    cell.isViewedImageView.isHidden = false
                }
            } else {
                cell.isViewedImageView.isHidden = true
            }
        // Messages to me.
        } else {
            cell.isViewedImageView.isHidden = true
            cell.bubbleView.backgroundColor = MessagesCell.bubbleGrayColor
            cell.messageTextView.textColor = .black
            cell.bubbleViewLeftAnchor?.isActive = true
            cell.bubbleViewRightAnchor?.isActive = false
            // Only show profile image for the last message in the chain of messages from partner.
            if isNextMessageFromAnotherSender(messages: messages, indexPath: indexPath) || isLastMessage(messages: messages, indexPath: indexPath) || nextMessageDisplaysTime(messages: messages, indexPath: indexPath) {
                cell.profileImageView.isHidden = false
            } else {
                cell.profileImageView.isHidden = true
            }
        }
        setupBubbleCorners(cell: cell, messages: messages, indexPath: indexPath)
    }
```

I simply set the color of the bubbles and color of the text and dimensions of elements dependent on if the message is from me or not from me.

I add new messages like this:

```
    override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
        let topEdge: CGFloat = 0
        guard let contentOffsetY = collectionView?.contentOffset.y else { return }
        let ceiledContentOffsetY = CGFloat(ceil(Double(contentOffsetY)))
        if ceiledContentOffsetY <= topEdge && okToAppendMessages && appendAmount < 3 {
            appendAmount = appendAmount + 1
            okToAppendMessages = false
//            print("Ok to append new messages")
            fetchMessagesForPagination(completion: { (newMessagesArrayReversed: [Message]) in
                if newMessagesArrayReversed.count < self.limit {
                    print("No more messages to load")
                    return
                }
                guard let beforeSize = self.collectionView?.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize else { return }
                self.messages = newMessagesArrayReversed + self.messages
                self.collectionViewReloadData(scrollToBottom: false)
                guard let afterSize = self.collectionView?.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize else { return }
                let diff = afterSize.height - beforeSize.height
                guard let contentOffsetX = self.collectionView?.contentOffset.x else { return }
                guard let contentOffsetY = self.collectionView?.contentOffset.y else { return }
                self.collectionView?.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: contentOffsetX, y: contentOffsetY + diff)
                self.okToAppendMessages = true
            })
        }
    }
```

The method that fetches messages for pagination:

```
private func fetchMessagesForPagination(completion: @escaping (_ newMessagesArrayReversed: [Message]) -> ()) {
    guard let messageThread = replyTo else { return }
    let urlString = "\(Config.URL)/api/messages/replyTo/\(messageThread)/offset/\(offset)"
    HttpService.get(urlString: urlString, viewController: self) { (json: JSON) in
        var newMessagesArray = [Message]()
        for messagesJSON in json["messages"].arrayValue {
            let message = Message(json: messagesJSON.dictionaryObject ?? [:])
            newMessagesArray.append(message)
        }
        newMessagesArray.reverse()
        self.offset = newMessagesArray.first?.id ?? 0
        completion(newMessagesArray)
    }
}
```

HttpService.get() is a wrapper around Alamofire.

MessagesCell:

```
class MessagesCell: BaseCell {

    var message: Message? {
        didSet {
            guard let message = message else { return }

            messageTextView.text = message.message

            // Load only image for messages sent from partner.
            if !message.isFromMe() {
                profileImageView.loadImage(urlString: User.imageURL(imageName: message.fromImage))
            }
        }
    }

    let messageTextView: UITextView = {
        let tv = UITextView()
        tv.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)
        tv.backgroundColor = .clear
//        tv.textColor = .white
        tv.isEditable = false
        return tv
    }()

    let profileImageView: CachedImageView = {
        let imageView = CachedImageView()
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 16
        imageView.isHidden = true
        return imageView
    }()

    let isViewedImageView: CachedImageView = {
        let imageView = CachedImageView()
        imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 8
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true
        imageView.isHidden = true
        return imageView
    }()

    let timeLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.textColor = UIColor.materialGray(level: 500)
//        label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 12)
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12)
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.isHidden = true
        return label
    }()

    static let bubbleBlueColor = UIColor.rgb(red: 0, green: 137, blue: 249)
    static let bubbleGrayColor = UIColor.rgb(red: 240, green: 240, blue: 240)

    let bubbleView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
//        view.backgroundColor = MessagesCell.bubbleBlueColor
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.layer.cornerRadius = 3
//        view.layer.cornerRadius = 16
        view.layer.masksToBounds = true
        return view
    }()

    var isViewedImageViewBottomAnchor: NSLayoutConstraint?

    var profileImageViewBottomAnchor: NSLayoutConstraint?

    var bubbleViewLeftAnchor: NSLayoutConstraint?
    var bubbleViewRightAnchor: NSLayoutConstraint?
    var bubbleViewWidthAnchor: NSLayoutConstraint?
    var bubbleViewTopAnchor: NSLayoutConstraint?
    var bubbleViewBottomAnchor: NSLayoutConstraint?

    override func setupViews() {
        super.setupViews()

        addSubview(profileImageView)
        addSubview(bubbleView)
        bubbleView.addSubview(messageTextView)
        addSubview(isViewedImageView)
        addSubview(timeLabel)

        profileImageView.anchor(top: nil, left: leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: nil, topConstant: 0, leftConstant: 8, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 0, widthConstant: 32, heightConstant: 32)
        profileImageViewBottomAnchor = profileImageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor)
        profileImageViewBottomAnchor?.isActive = true

        bubbleViewLeftAnchor = bubbleView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: profileImageView.rightAnchor, constant: 8)
        bubbleViewLeftAnchor?.isActive = false

        let rightConstant: CGFloat = -16 - 2 - 2
        bubbleViewRightAnchor = bubbleView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor, constant: rightConstant)
        bubbleViewRightAnchor?.isActive = true

        bubbleViewWidthAnchor = bubbleView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 230)
        bubbleViewWidthAnchor?.isActive = true

        bubbleViewTopAnchor = bubbleView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor)
        bubbleViewTopAnchor?.isActive = true

        bubbleViewBottomAnchor = bubbleView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor)
        bubbleViewBottomAnchor?.isActive = true

        messageTextView.anchor(top: bubbleView.topAnchor, left: bubbleView.leftAnchor, bottom: bubbleView.bottomAnchor, right: bubbleView.rightAnchor, topConstant: 0, leftConstant: 8, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 0, widthConstant: 0, heightConstant: 0)

        isViewedImageView.anchor(top: nil, left: nil, bottom: nil, right: rightAnchor, topConstant: 0, leftConstant: 0, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: -2, widthConstant: 16, heightConstant: 16)
        isViewedImageViewBottomAnchor = isViewedImageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor)
        isViewedImageViewBottomAnchor?.isActive = true

        timeLabel.anchor(top: nil, left: leftAnchor, bottom: bubbleView.topAnchor, right: rightAnchor, topConstant: 0, leftConstant: 0, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 0, widthConstant: 0, heightConstant: 30)
    }

}
```

This is one the most annoying bugs I have ever encountered, I have no idea where it comes from because it makes no sense because it is only the textColor of 1 message, not the bubble color or position, just the textColor.

Comment: Keep it simple, don't do so much formatting at `tableView:cellForRowAt:`. Instead create 2 separate cells and register them separately. You can dequeue by the cellD and would be better and easier to manage.

Comment: Two separate cells for two users you mean?

Comment: Yup, one for blue cell and one for grey cell. It would be faster and cleaner that way.